Environments Dashboard does not show pipeline for repos which are not deployed in all the environments
We have project group in GitLab with a set of repos. And there are five environments (feature, develop, test, stage and Production). Below is the description of the problem with a sample project group.
Project Group: PG1
  -- Application repo: App1
  -- Application dependency module one: dep1
  -- Application dependency module two: dep2

Application App1 consumes dependencies dep1 and dep2. The pipeline for the dependencies are run till the test environment where the releases are created.  Application App1 pipeline is run in all the environments.
When the Environment Dashboard is created with all these projects the pipeline status is only shown for App1. For the dependency projects only title is show and status panels are not shown. The dashboard is looking roughly as below.
Environments Dashboard
PG1 > dep1
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PG1 > dep2
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PG1 > App1
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Production pipeline status for App1,   Stage pipeline status for App1,  Test pipeline status for App1
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

We are expecting the pipeline status for dependency projects in the Test environment. However it is not shown. Not sure if we are missing any thing. Could you please help.
Versions
GitLab Enterprise Edition 17.0.0
